# Add a dropdown for different profile sections next to the username at the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

I understand you guys like to keep it simple and minimalistic, but drop-downs are really needed for the user-account link, so I can hop over directly to my asked question, recent activity etc.

<sub>(quick mockup removed, image is broken)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Now implemented -- note the clickable areas:

[![][1]][1]

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/r-i-p-envelope-hello-improved-user-pages/
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCOgb.png

Answer (score 0):

Current method:

- Click account link.
- (optional) Click desired secondary destination.

New method:

- Click dropdown to open.
- Click desired secondary destination.

How is this proposal better? It's either the same or more clicks to do anything.

Comment: It's the same clicks, but fewer page refreshes.

Comment: Not everyone has xxmbps connection like you, fortunately, do. :-)

Comment: I don't think that click-count is the be-all and end-all of usability metrics.

Comment: Could also work via a hover - in a asimilar manner to the menus on Flickr